# Troubles with NSString writeToFile

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have been working on a simple text editor in Cocoa/Objective-C for a practice project, and I have come across an error that I would never have expected.

I have an NSString for my file's contents as well as an NSString for it's path. When I attempt to write the contents to a file, I use the following method:

```
[FileContents writeToFile: CurrentFileName 
               atomically: NO 
                 encoding: NSStringEncoding /* Error occurs on this line */
                    error: nil];
```

I've used this method many times without error yet today, I am getting an error:

> Expected expression before 'NSStringEncoding'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSStringEncoding isn't a valid value. You need to decide what [text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) to use. If you don't know anything about text encodings and these files are only used by your program, I would recommend using NSUTF8StringEncoding everywhere.

UTF-8 has many benefits, including that it is plain ASCII if you don't encounter any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out my mistake as soon as I posted it. Note to self: Don't try to program on low levels of sleep =)

Comment: If this is the right answer, don't forget to click the √ next to the left.

Answer (score 3):

NSStringEncoding is a type, not a value. You need to specify *which* NSStringEncoding you want (e.g. NSUTF8StringEncoding, NSASCIIStringEncoding and so on).